# jquery textarea add link in text with costum popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textarea where users can enter some text en sometimes they use a little html in there to make it look better. Sometimes this goes a wrong so I tried to make it easier for them by adding a few images with functions. Like wrapping text in `<b> <i> <u> <del>` tags. This works great. Only now I want them to add url's and this is where I got stuck.

What I want:

<del>I want a popup with a title bar and a url bar. after pressing `OK` I want the text to appear in the textarea where the user had left his cursor. the text in the textarea needs to look like `<a href="' + url + '" rel="external">' + title + '</a>`. If a user selects some text i want that to appear in the popup title field.</del>

- If the `add link` button is pressed the script needs to look if there is a selection in the textarea
- if there is a selection the script remembers that
- the popup opens
- in the title-input of the popup the selection appears.
- the user fills in the url
- the user presses the OK button
- the popup disappears and the selected text gets replaced by a link
- the link looks like `<a href="' + url + '" rel="external">' + title + '</a>`

this is some code I have:

```
    function wrapAsLink(url) {
        var textArea = $('.area'),
            len = textarea.value.length,
            start = textarea.selectionStart,
            end = textarea.selectionEnd,
            sel = textarea.value.substring(start, end),
            replace = '<a href="'+url+'" rel="external">' + sel + '</a>';
        textarea.value = textarea.value.substring(0,start) + replace + textarea.value.substring(end,len);
        $('.area').keyup();
    }
```

and a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/niekdemelker/T2Q89/2/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

[The fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/2bL3826n/1/)

Change your html as:

```
<div class="editor">
    <div class="toolbar">
        <span id="btnedit-bold" title="Vergedrukte text"><img src="images/bold.png" /></span>
        <span id="btnedit-italic" title="Italic text"><img src="images/italic.png" /></span>
        <span id="btnedit-underline" title="Onderstreep text"><img src="images/underline.png" /></span>
        <span id="divider">&nbsp;</span>
        <span id="btnedit-delete" title="verwijder (doorstreep) text"><img src="images/delete.png" /></span>
        <span id="divider">&nbsp;</span>
        <span id="btnedit-link" title="Insert link"><img src="images/link.png" /></span>
    </div>
    <textarea name="editor-preview" class="area" placeholder="Uw bericht"></textarea>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div class="editor-preview"></div>

<div id="prompt">
    <div class="prompt-background"></div>
    <div class="prompt-dialog">
        <div class="prompt-message">
            <p><b>Insert Hyperlink</b></p>
        </div>
        <form class="prompt-form">
            <p>titel</p>
            <input id="btnedit-title" type="text" style="display: block; width: 80%; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;">
            <p>http://example.com/</p>
            <input id="btnedit-url" type="text" style="display: block; width: 80%; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;">
            <button id="btnedit-ok" class="btn-orange" onClick="$('#prompt').show();">OK</button>
            <button id="btnedit-cancel" class="btn-orange" onClick="$('#prompt').hide();">cancel</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And add those to your javascript as:

```
$('#btnedit-bold').on("click",function(e) {
    wrapText('b');
});

$('#btnedit-italic').on("click",function(e) {
    wrapText('i');
});

$('#btnedit-underline').on("click",function(e) {
    wrapText('u');
});

$('#btnedit-delete').on("click",function(e) {
    wrapText('del');
});

$('#btnedit-link').on("click",function(e) {
    var textArea = $('.area'),
        len = textArea.val().length,
        start = textArea[0].selectionStart,
        end = textArea[0].selectionEnd,
        selectedText = textArea.val().substring(start, end);
    $('#btnedit-title').val(selectedText);
    $('#btnedit-url').val('http://');
    $('#prompt').show();
});

$('#btnedit-ok').on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#prompt').hide();
    replacement = '<a title="'+$('#btnedit-title').val()+'" href="'+$('#btnedit-url').val()+'" rel="external">' + $('#btnedit-title').val() + '</a>';
    wrapLink(replacement);
}); 

$('#btnedit-cancel').on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#prompt').hide();
}); 

function wrapLink(link) {
    var textArea = $('.area'),
        len = textArea.val().length,
        start = textArea[0].selectionStart,
        end = textArea[0].selectionEnd,
        selectedText = textArea.val().substring(start, end);
    textArea.val(textArea.val().substring(0, start) + link + textArea.val().substring(end, len));
    $('.area').keyup();
}
```

Comment: I think I did something wrong couse when I add your changes none of the scripts work. see [my new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/niekdemelker/T2Q89/3/)

Comment: to see all are functioning check this fiddle, as in jsfiddle within tag functions may not properly work with the options selected: http://jsfiddle.net/T2Q89/5/

but the above part will work if you try in your browser as with saving it to a html file and running it

Comment: This it the single page i created. The jquery included stands local. It still doesn't do anything. As if there is no script at all. [a jsfiddle with total source in de html section](http://jsfiddle.net/niekdemelker/ra4Jy/)

Comment: In the fiddle you created jquery is not included hence, that creates a problem in jsfiddle, i've updated it and divided them: http://jsfiddle.net/ra4Jy/1/

Comment: you said I must run it localy om my computer couse jsfiddle could couse problems. so i did. As you can see in my last commend I put in there the file i run localy. only it does not work. The new fiddle you gave also doesn't work :(.

Comment: ah sorry i got it, anyway which browser are you using, as i am using firefox 30 and it is working.

Comment: Google chrome 35.0.1916.153 and internet explorer 11 (only for testing). it really works like there is no script at all from here.

Comment: it's interesting, this is the screenshot also of the latest fiddle i've sent : http://i59.tinypic.com/wb58qh.png

Comment: can you copy the whole html from here and tell me the result: http://pastebin.com/ZfeeaYJp

Comment: haha. i've seen it. just installed firefox. also good for testing. i see it works there. only in google chrome and IE 11 it does not work. so its not good because it has to work in all the populair browsers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56911/discussion-between-user3602420-and-burak).

Comment: Hello Burak. I have been working with the scripts you've provided me. I hope my last question will not be to hard for you only I cant figure it out. I have made a new jsfiddle.net/niekdemelker/… fiddle. the part i have works well in chrome as in firefox. only not the apply button. maybe you could help me one more time with the $('#btnedit-ok').on("click",function(e) and the $('#btnedit-link').on("click",function(e).